# How to append user input from one file to another Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I need to create a program that asks the user to put their user name and their password and if that is correct I have to put the user name and the password into a new pickle. I think the problem is because I'm trying to put that in a list and then append function can't use functions.

```
import pickle

customer_pck = open("customer_file.pck", "rb")
username_and_password_list = pickle.load(customer_pck)
customer_pck.close()

username_and_password_list.insert()
print(username_and_password_list)


def password_check(password):
    symbols = ['!', '£', '$', '%', '&', '@', '#', '?']
    validation = True

    if len(password) < 8:
        print("Length should be at least 8 characters")
        validation = False
    if len(password) > 16:
        print("Length should be no more than 16 characters")
        validation = False
    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
        print("Password should have at least one number")
        validation = False
    if not any(char.isupper() for char in password):
        print("Password should have at least one upper case letter")
        validation = False
    if not any(char.islower() for char in password):
        print("Passwordd should have at least one lower case letter")
        validation = False
    if not any(char in symbols for char in password):
        print("Password should have at least one of the special symbols: ! £ $ % & @ # ?")
        validation = False
    if validation:
        return validation


def new_customer():
    first_name = input("Enter your first name: ")  # need to put this into file
    last_name = input("Enter your last name: ")  # need to put this into file
    print(f'Username: {slice_username(first_name[slice(3)])}{slice_username(last_name[slice(3)])}')

    passwrd = input("Enter your password: ")

    while not password_check(passwrd) == True:
        passwrd = input("Enter your password: ")
```

Comment: where's the place you create a new pickle with user input added? don't see that in your code.

Comment: import pickle

    customer = []

    customer_file = open("customer_file.pck", "wb")

    pickle.dump(customer,customer_file)

    customer_file.close()

    print(customer)

Comment: the place you quoted opens file, reads and closes it back. don't see anything new added to the file contents.